# Devise's sign_in_after_reset_password doesn't seem to do what its name suggests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

Devise's `sign_in_after_reset_password` setting supposedly signs in my user after successfully resetting the password.

However, what it seems to do in practice is to redirect back to '/', which ultimately results in showing the login page.

Why isn't it signing me in?

In `user.rb`:

```
  devise :database_authenticatable,
         :recoverable,
         :validatable,
         :encryptable
```

In `application_controller.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_action :authenticate_user!, unless: :devise_controller?
  #omitting business logic filters and helpers
end
```

Custom routes (solely to change the paths. Have tried to keep the resulting route list identical to the defaults other than the names):

```
  devise_for :users, skip: [ :passwords, :sessions ]
  devise_scope :user do
    get 'users/login' => 'devise/sessions#new', as: 'new_user_session'
    post 'users/login' => 'devise/sessions#create', as: 'user_session'
    delete 'users/logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: 'destroy_user_session'

    post 'users/password' => 'devise/passwords#create', as: 'user_password'
    get 'users/password/forgot' => 'devise/passwords#new', as: 'new_user_password'
    get 'users/password/reset' => 'devise/passwords#edit', as: 'edit_user_password'
    patch 'users/password' => 'devise/passwords#update', as: nil
    put 'users/password' => 'devise/passwords#update', as: nil
  end
```

The investigation so far:

- I had a lot of minor deviations from the structure of a sample devise application which I have been golfing back bit by bit to try and make things easier to figure out. So now my `authenticate_user!` filter is being specified in the same place as most examples.
- Something I noticed is that after successfully resetting the password, it isn't clearing the reset password token. Maybe that's normal, it's just suspicious.
- I have debugged in Devise's `PasswordsController` itself and after it executes the `sign_in` line, `signed_in?` does return true.
- I have *attempted* to breakpoint inside `signed_in?` at the point of requesting the root path, but it seems like I get the 401 error from the web server without `signed_in?` ever being called. So perhaps Warden is directly kicking me out before the application even gets to run.

I'm starting to run out of avenues for investigation, so I thought I would post it here in case anyone had seen the exact same issue before.

Logs of the event:

```
Started PUT "/users/password" for ::1 at 2016-07-13 17:14:44 +1000
Processing by Devise::PasswordsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"reset_password_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Change my password"}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."reset_password_token" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["reset_password_token", "[FILTERED]"]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  Note Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "notes".* FROM "notes" WHERE "notes"."notable_id" = ? AND "notes"."notable_type" = ?  [["notable_id", 2], ["notable_type", "User"]]
  Organisation Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "organisations".* FROM "organisations" WHERE "organisations"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."login" = 'test1' AND "users"."id" != 2) LIMIT 1
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Completed 302 Found in 44ms (ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)


Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2016-07-13 17:14:44 +1000
Processing by SessionsController#welcome as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/users/login" for ::1 at 2016-07-13 17:14:44 +1000
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered users/shared/_links.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered users/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 148ms (Views: 147.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: do you have an `after_sign_in_path` set? http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Controllers/Helpers:after_sign_in_path_for

If not - you'll probably get redirected to the root path... which in your case is `/`

Comment: I set it explicitly to `'/'` because I wasn't sure what it was defaulting to. But the root path also requires authentication. I'm adding logs to show that indeed it does redirect there, but then gets a 401.

Comment: ok, but I guess I was answering your question "why isn't it signing me in?" with "it is... it's just then redirecting you back to the root path"... if you want it to redirect you somewhere else after signing in, then you need to change after_signin_path_for. If you want h3e root path to show whether or not you're signed in, you'll need something on the page that indicates it eg `if signed_in? puts "Welcome to my site" else 'login here'` or whatever...

Comment: I think getting a 401 when visiting the root path is pretty conclusively saying that the user is not signed in. See the logs I edited into the question.

Comment: So it seems like perhaps the question could now read, "Why is Devise immediately signing me out after signing me in?"

Comment: How about this: just try an after_sign_in_path _for... that is different form the root path... doesn't matter what as long as it's a page that you have to be signed in to see... and see what happens.
I have this vague memory of there being something slightly different you have to do for a page that serves as both login and non-logged-in. This is why I am pushing you to actually try this tack. Once you have tried it and seen whether or not it works... then we can distinguish this option from any other problem that is going on.

Comment: The actual sign-in page is not /, you just happen to see the sign-in page if you visit / without being signed in. So it isn't serving as both login and non-logged-in, you can only see it if you're logged in. So anyway, just now I tried overriding `after_sign_in_path_for` to return `'/users/me'` instead. The result is that it now redirects to that, which returns 401 and redirects back to /users/login.

Comment: yes, but I'd be guessing that '/' is visible to users that aren't logged in. As I recall there is a special before_action that needs to be added to all actions that can be *both* logged in and also public. So it's not that `/` is the sign-in page... but that it is visible in both logged-in and not logged-in states. Still... cool to know that that isn't the issue... there's something else. You possibly need some kind of skip-authentication on the actual authenticating action.

Comment: The only thing that kills me is that I can't see why it is signing them in with a "poisoned" user account which is immediately rejected for access in the very next action, when if I sign in manually, the same doesn't happen and I can access the front page with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not really answering the question itself, but I found a workaround which is at least a solution, even if it's a *bad* solution.

In my `ApplicationController`:

```
  after_action :fix_login_after_password_reset, if: ->(controller) {
    controller.controller_path == 'devise/passwords' &&
      controller.action_name == 'update'
  }

  def fix_login_after_password_reset
    user = current_user
    if user && user.errors.empty?
      user = User.where(id: user.id).first
      sign_out
      bypass_sign_in(user)
    end
  end
```

Essentially, I found a post where people who wrote their own "change password" pages found that Devise (or Warden?) was logging out the user immediately afterwards. The workaround for them was to change the call to `sign_in` to `bypass_sign_in`.

In this situation, though, Devise have already called `sign_in`. So I thought I'd try adding a filter that applies onto to their one action with the problem, and sign the user out, then sign in a fresh copy of the user. This fixes the issue - now the user is signed in and the root page appears.

I don't like this solution much though so I'm still digging inside Warden to try and figure out why the user is not being signed in with a call to `sign_in`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and found that passing an extra parameter to the `sign_up` function solves the problem:

```
sign_in(@user, :bypass => true)
```

This was something I found [in this tutorial](http://sourcey.com/rails-4-omniauth-using-devise-with-twitter-facebook-and-linkedin/) for setting up omniauth with a `finish_signup` feature. My implementation below is part of a feature I'm writing for a user to change their password and still retain their status as a logged in user.

---

~/app/controllers/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_current_user, only: [:edit_password, :update_password]

    def edit_password
    end

    def update_password
      if @user.update(user_params)
        # Sign in the user by passing validation in case their password changed
        sign_in(@user, :bypass => true)
        redirect_to root_path
      else
        render :edit_password
      end
    end

    private
    def set_current_user
      @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    end
end
```

---

~/app/views/users/edit_password.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@user, :url => { :action => "update_password" } ) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password, "Password" %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, :autocomplete => "off"  %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  </div>
  <div class="action_container">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

---

routes.rb

```
resource :user, only: [:none] do
    collection do
      get :edit_password
      patch :update_password
    end
  end
```